# Set up a shared folder for users on a Linux server

Tags: linux, unix

I have a folder `/mnt/disk/folder`.

1. I want `user1` and `user2` to both have full recursive read+write access to any current and future directories and files.
2. I want to symlink the folder to `/home/user1/data/` and `/home/user2/data/` with access rights maintained.

This is what I have done:

Make the directory

`mkdir /mnt/disk/folder`

Symlink the to the directory

```
ln -s /mnt/disk/folder /home/user1/data
ln -s /mnt/disk/folder /home/user2/data
```

Make a group for sharing

`sudo groupadd sharing`

Add users to that group

```
sudo usermod -a -G sharing user1
sudo usermod -a -G sharing user2
```

Chown all existing files (not any in this case) to belong to the group

`sudo chgrp -R sharing /mnt/disk/folder`

Make all existing files (not any in this case) group-read-write

`sudo chmod g+rw -R /mnt/disk/folder`

Ensure that all newly created files and directories will belong to the group

```
chgrp sharing /mnt/disk/folder
chmod g+s /mnt/disk/folder
```

If logged in as `user1` doing `mkdir /home/user1/data/folder/123`it works.
As does `cd 123` and `>test.txt`.

If then logging in as `user2` and navigating to `/home/user1/data/folder/`, the stuff created by `user1` is there, and both users can create, edit, and remove directories and files.

I run a JupyterHub server, however, where user1 and user2 access their directories through jupyter's browser interface. When creating and editing here, permissions do NOT work.

Answer (score 2):

## Part 2: The Symlink

The second part is easy: Symlinks always maintain permissions in the sense that you would expect. Thus create them simply by `ln -s`:

```
ln -s /mnt/disk/folder /home/user1/data
ln -s /mnt/disk/folder /home/user2/data
```

(In case you are using applications which fail to work correctly with the symlink, consider using a bind mount).

## Part 1: Correct access permissions

This is the "more tricky" part, because it depends (at least in part) on the cooperation of the users. The basic UNIX approach to this kind of problem is to make both users (`user1` and `user2`) part of the same group (e.g. `dataaccess`). Then, all existing data needs to be chown'ed to belong to that group e.g. by means of a command like this:

```
chgrp -R dataaccess /mnt/disk/folder
```

Finally, all the files in the directory need to be group-read-write, which can e.g. be achieved by a `chmod g+rw -R /mnt/disk/folder` for the existing files.

Having established access to the existing files, the user cooperation comes into play: All newly created files and directories need to belong to the group and need to have the `g+rw` bits set. The correct setting of permissions can be achieved by configuring a suitable `umask` for both of the users.

The last step is to ensure that newly created files and directories belong to the correct group. This can be done manually by the users by invoking suitable `chgrp` commands after they created files or automated by means of the setgid bit, see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/51951/set-default-group-for-user-when-they-create-new-files.

If you cannot rely on the users to create files which only they have access to, you could establish an automated permission-widening mechanism by means of a cronjob or inotify.

Another "sledgehammer approach" which comes with a lot of problematic side-effects is the use of a filesystem which does not support permissions and will thus always have (mount-time-configurable) access permissions. FAT32 comes to mind, but it is highly recommendable to use the cleaner solution outlined before instead!

Comment: Thanks for this! I still get permission errors, though.

Comment: Would you mind updating the description of the problem with information about how the permissions are wrong? It would be interesting to see the sequence of commands `: > test.txt` followed by `ls -lah` and possibly also `stat .` and `stat test.txt`?

Comment: I have now updated the problem description.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still not exactly sure in what mode it fails. So from only the users' point of view it works already, but it does not work when accessing the files through the server? What permissions does the server set on the files? (e.g. an `ls -l` output for a file created by the server would be interesting). Additoinally, what user does the server run under? What `umask`  is active for the server process?

Comment: The server runs under `sudo`, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. Running servers as root is generally considered bad practice. I would suggest creating a user called `dataaccess` (just like the group) and make that user's primary group the `dataaccess` group which already exists. Then run the server under that user (with `umask 0002`) such that all files created by the server running under that user are accessible